# Apache Airflow logo path

Tags: python, airflow, flask-appbuilder

I am new to the python world and recently started trying out Apache Airflow. I did a little bit of reading and started installing Airflow in my Ubuntu (Using WSL2 on Windows). I am trying to understand from where the apache logo (rotation image) is loaded?

Why is required for me?

1. For my learning
2. I am trying to add my own logo adjacent to Apache Logo

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logo is animated using CSS:

https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/d2bdf05cf04414ec2c973cdec0f970bf96c3a0e2/airflow/www/static/css/main.css#L98

The image to animate is taken from here:

https://github.com/apache/airflow/tree/main/airflow/www/static

Comment: Thank you. Have spotted a place for my logo too.

Comment: How did you go about changing the logo? What files have to be modified?

Comment: I did not change the logo but tried adding one more part of my trial. I think I tried modifying the file "apache-airflow/airflow/www/templates/appbuilder/navbar.html"